# Forcing a paragraph on a new page when using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: vb.net, interop, ms-word

I have the following VB.Net code to create a Microsoft Word document. How can I force the "Second Paragraph." to be on the next page (a new page)?

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Dim wordApp As Word._Application = New  _
    Word.ApplicationClass()

    Dim wordDoc As Word._Document = _
        wordApp.Documents.Add()

    Dim para As Word.Paragraph = wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add()
    para.Range.Text = "First Paragraph."
    para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()

    para.Range.Text = "Second Paragraph."
    para.Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use InsertBreak to start a new page:

```
  Selection.InsertBreak
```

[WdBreakType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195905.aspx)

Comment: Thanks! For my example para.Range.InsertBreak() did the trick.